# What is faster cutting or copying a file?

Tags: hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

To get large file from one place to another what is faster cutting or copying a file ? What factors can influence the result? 
I've heard it matters if they are on the same drive and the speed of the drive, but don't know for sure.

Answer (score 29):

It depends on some factors.

If you're moving the file on the same drive and partition it will be faster to cut/paste than to copy since it's not actually moving the data.

If it's across partition or drive boundries it will always be a copy or copy+erase so the difference is minimal.

Answer (score 8):

On the same disk, cutting, by a considerable margin.
On different disks, Copying, by virtue of cutting would require the original to be deleted, which would take a tiny amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

If we are cutting(moving) within a same disk, then it will be faster than copying because only the file path is modified, actual data is on the disk.

On the other hand, if the data is moved(cut) from one disk to another, it does 2 things, copying files to another partition, also deleting the main data from source. So time taken will be (copy+delete)

If the data is copied from one disk to another, it will be relatively faster than cutting because it is doing only COPY operation.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing faster than nothing.

Same drive >

Moving is instant

Copying is slower

Different drive >

Moving is Copying + Erase original data

Copying is Copying

The fact is that erasing a bigger file takes little time to be deleted.